# Для чего используют parent в методе?

Tags: php

Есть класс A, он наследует класс B и у класса A есть метод testing и в этом методе есть `parent::testing();` Для чего это указывается? Что он делает? Расскажите пожалуйста с примерами.

Comment: Читай [руководство](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php#language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parent::метод();` используется для того чтобы вызвать метод не текущего класса, а класса-родителя.

Пример:

```php
<?php
  $object = new Son;
  $object->test();
  $object->test2();

  class Dad
  {
    fuction test()
    {
      echo "[Class Dad] 1";
    }
  }

  class Son extends Dad
  {
    function test()
    {
      echo "[Class Son] 2";
    }
    
    function test2()
    {
      parent::test();
    }
  }
?>
```

- Пример из книги `Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, CSS и HTML5`